# Proving a constructed approximating sequence in a Banach space converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, banach-spaces

Suppose that $(V,\|\cdot\|)$ is a Banach space. Let $S_n$ be a sequence of closed sets such that $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} S_n = V$ and $S_n \subseteq S_m$ for $n\leq m$.

Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a converging sequence in $V$ and define a new sequence $(\hat{x}_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ where each $\hat{x}_n\in S_n$ such that $\|x_n - \hat{x}_n\| = \min_{x\in S_n}\|x_n-x\|$.

Does it follow that $\| x_n - \hat{x}_n\|\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: But if $\hat{x}_n\in S_n$, doesn't if follow that $\min_{x\in S_n} ||x-\hat{x}_n||\leq ||\hat{x}_n-\hat{x}_n||=0$?

Comment: @Mark it is probably a typo, and it should be $\min\|x-x_n\|$ which defines $\hat{x}_n$

Comment: It should be noted that $\hat {x_n}$  need not exist and if it exists it need not be unique. However one can still ask this question assuming the existence of $\hat {x_n}$ .

Comment: @Mark It was indeed a typo and I have since corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you meant that $\hat {x_n} \in S_n$ and  $\|x_n-\hat {x_n}\|=\inf_{y \in S_n} \|x_n-y\|$. Let $x_n \to x$. Then $x \in S_k$ for some $k$. For $n   \geq k$ we have $x \in S_n$ so  $\|x_n-\hat {x_n}\|\leq \|x_n-x\| \to 0$.